Angular 17: Issues with Admin Module Routing and Standalone Components
`Hey everyone,
I'm currently working on an Angular project, and I'm facing some challenges with routing within my admin module. Specifically, I'm encountering issues when navigating to child routes under the admin section. I've organized my components using standalone routing and I'm running into problems with blank pages and missing assets.
To add some context, I haven't integrated AuthGuard for admin routes or implemented login logic yet.
I've tried troubleshooting the problem by adjusting my routing configuration and ensuring that asset paths are correct. However, I haven't been able to pinpoint the root cause of the issue.
Could someone please review my routing setup and provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[// admin-routing.module.ts://app.routes.ts](https://i.sstatic.net/JpC5iS62.png)
